# How to connect to amazon-lightsail via PHP CURL and list all instance?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, amazon-lightsail

I want to communicate with `amazon lightsail` with `PHP curl` instead of `SDK` because I did not wont to use composer in my project and I want to use a small number of functions at all in SDK so I try to do it via curl

When I execute the code blow I get this response

```
<?php
// set our constants
define('SERVICE'    , 'lightsail');
define('ACCESS_KEY' , 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('SECRET_KEY' , 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('REGION'     , 'eu-west-2');
define('PROFILE'    , 'default');
define('VERSION'    , '20161128');
define('COMMAND'    , 'getInstances');

class AWS{
    static  $utc_tz;
    function lightsail( $payload ){
        self::$utc_tz = new \DateTimeZone( 'UTC' );
        $APIVERSION = VERSION;
        $datestamp  = new \DateTime( "now", self::$utc_tz );
        $longdate   = $datestamp->format( "Ymd\\THis\\Z");
        $shortdate  = $datestamp->format( "Ymd" );
        // establish the signing key

        $ksecret    = 'AWS4' . SECRET_KEY;
        $kdate      = hash_hmac( 'sha256', $shortdate, $ksecret, true );
        $kregion    = hash_hmac( 'sha256', REGION, $kdate, true );
        $kservice   = hash_hmac( 'sha256', SERVICE, $kregion, true );
        $ksigning   = hash_hmac( 'sha256', 'aws4_request', $kservice, true );

        // command parameters
        $params     = array(
            'host'          => SERVICE.'.'.REGION.'.amazonaws.com',
            'content-type'  => 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
            'x-amz-date'    => $longdate,
            'x-amz-target'  => SERVICE.'_'. $APIVERSION . '.'.COMMAND,
            'content-length' => strlen( $payload ),
            'user-agent'    => 'LDP',
            'connection'    => 'keep-alive',
        );
        $canonical_request  = $this->createCanonicalRequest( $params, $payload );
        $signed_request     = hash( 'sha256', $canonical_request );
        $sign_string        = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n{$longdate}\n$shortdate/".REGION."/".SERVICE."/aws4_request\n" . $signed_request;
        $signature          = hash_hmac( 'sha256', $sign_string, $ksigning );
        $params['authorization'] = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=" . ACCESS_KEY . "/$shortdate/".REGION."/".SERVICE."/aws4_request, " .
            "SignedHeaders=" . implode( ";", array_keys( $params ) )  . ", " .
            "Signature=$signature";
        /*
         * Execute Crafted Request
         */
        $url    = "https://".SERVICE.".".REGION.".amazonaws.com";
        $ch     = curl_init();
        $curl_headers = array();
        foreach( $params as $p => $k )
            $curl_headers[] = $p . ": " . $k;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        // debug opts

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
        $result = curl_exec($ch); // raw result
        rewind($verbose);
        $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
        echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";

        var_dump( $result );
    }
    private function createCanonicalRequest( $params, $payload ){
        $canonical_request      = array();
        $canonical_request[]    = 'POST';
        $canonical_request[]    = '/';
        $canonical_request[]    = '';
        $can_headers            = array(
            'host' => SERVICE.'.'.REGION.'.amazonaws.com'
        );
        foreach( $params as $k => $v )
            $can_headers[ strtolower( $k ) ] = trim( $v );
        uksort( $can_headers, 'strcmp' );
        foreach ( $can_headers as $k => $v )
            $canonical_request[] = $k . ':' . $v;
        $canonical_request[] = '';
        $canonical_request[] = implode( ';', array_keys( $can_headers ) );
        $canonical_request[] = hash( 'sha256', $payload );
        $canonical_request = implode( "\n", $canonical_request );
        return $canonical_request;
    }
}
$a = new AWS();
$a->lightsail( '{
  "instanceName": "vodo.website"
}');


Verbose information:
* Rebuilt URL to: https://lightsail.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/
*   Trying 52.94.56.147...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to lightsail.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com (52.94.56.147) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: c:\cert\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: CN=lightsail.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
*    start date: 2019-10-04 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2020-09-25 12:00:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST / HTTP/1.1
host: lightsail.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
Accept: */*
content-type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
x-amz-date: 20191023T063052Z
x-amz-target: lightsail_20161128.getInstances
content-length: 38
user-agent: LDP
connection: keep-alive
authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/20191023/eu-west-2/lightsail/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;content-type;x-amz-date;x-amz-target;content-length;user-agent;connection, Signature=389a5fc1aaa37bbb046faac409c52fc337585c7b8223e8abac6952e4060f989b

* upload completely sent off: 38 out of 38 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Server
< Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2019 06:30:56 GMT
< Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
< Content-Length: 38
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: 2cf0ef21-bee3-4430-ac98-a6986a5cafcb
< 
* Connection #0 to host lightsail.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com left intact
string(38) "{"__type":"UnknownOperationException"}"
```

I expect the output of all my instances instead of `UnknownOperationException`